# How to get rid of "Method parameters should be @State classes" in JMH when parameters come from another method?

Tags: java, microbenchmark, jmh

I'm working on a maven project. The scenario is something like below...

```
class Test {

    public void applyAll() {
        ....................
        ....................
        Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates = SomeOtherClass.getApplicableUpdates();
        doUpdate(applicableUpdates);

    }

    @Benchmark
    public void apply(Migratable m) {
        ....................
        ....................
    }

    private void doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates) throws Exception {
        for (Migratable m : applicableUpdates) {
            try {

                apply(m);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Falid to apply migration {}" + m, e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to compute how long it takes to execute each migration. Simply I need to compute the execution time of **apply(Migratable m)** method. 
Now, when I build my project using "mvn clean install", build failed and it shows "Method parameters should be @State classes". 
 
Here, parameter comes from another method **doUpdate(Collection applicableUpdates)** [see the scenario]. So how can I get rid of this error in given scenario?

Comment: You look up the JMH documentation and you run the performance test with JMH. If you are having trouble with that, you can come back to StackOverflow with a *specific* question.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBolwidt. Think this time you'll understand the problem I'm facing. Actually, I'm stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a few problems in your setup here and it seems you haven't actually looked at the samples of JMH; and I strongly advise you to do that.

A few notes...

1) You `@Benchmark` method returns void - it should return `something`; otherwise use `BlackHoles` (this is in the samples).

2)  If parameters comes from *another method* it means that method should be a `@SetUp` method (this is in the samples)

3) The error that you are seeing has to do with the fact that your `Migratable` is not actually a `@State` class (this is again in the samples!)

At this point I can't stress that enough - but look and *understand* the samples. It's not going to be easy, this is micro-benchmark and as much as JMH tries to make things easier for us by hiding all the *very complicated* code, it still requires us to conform to the rules that exist there.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene
`Migratable` is an interface and State does not support abstract classes. 
And seeing [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/36a2ee9a075e/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_04_DefaultState.java) sample, it seems to me that `@Benchmark` can return void.
Actually I'm new on this topic and still stuck.

Comment: @neelrotno for void methods read the samples about `BlackHole`. You will see that the sample that you provided is said to *measure wrong*. Its ok being new to the subject, we all were at some point in time. I use JMH for a lot of time and still get things wrong sometimes...

Comment: @Eugene...actually I cannot apply `Blackholes' in my project seeing the sample.  Now please, consider...you have this Test class. If you have to compute how long `apply(Migratable m)` method takes in each time it is being called, how would you do that? It'll be helpful for me if you give the exact code with appropriate annotation(s)

Comment: Here, `applyAll()` method get applicableUpdates from another class and pass it to `doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates)`. `doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates)` method pass each of the element of the list `aplicableUpdates` to `apply(Migratable m)` method. `apply(Migratable m)` method just update DB and return void.